# How much faster are out machines (generally) than Arthur C. Clarke's machine in 1953's "The 9 Billion Names of God"?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

In Arthur C. Clarke's short story, "The 9 Billion Names of God", two software/hardware engineers are contracted by a monastery to generate 9 billion string permutations from a 13-character alphabet. The only rules are that no character can occur 4 times in a row and each string must be 9 characters long. They estimate that the amount of processing time is 2,000 hours of computer time. The story was written in 1953.

For fun, using that same algorithm, I want to determine how much faster my current desktop (Mac Pro 3.2 GHz 16-Core Intel Xeon W) is than the fictional machine of ACC's 1953.

Instead of running the whole thing, which would take a while, I generated all the "a" words (those beginning with "a") and timed it. On my desktop, it took 1,358 seconds.

1,358 * 13 chars == 17,654 total seconds ~= 5 hours.

2,000 / 5 == my machine is **400x** faster than ACC's 1953 machine. But that doesn't feel right. That's a lot, sure, but I figured it would be more.

Is my math wrong?

```
Swift

// 13-char alphabet
let letters: [Character] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "k", "l", "m", "n"]

func shangriLa(_ name: String) -> [String] {
  if name.count == 9 {
    return [name]
  }
  var names = [String]()
  for letter in letters {
    if (name.count <= 2) || canAppendLetter(name, letter: letter) {
      names.append(contentsOf: shangriLa(name + String(letter)))
    }
  }
  return names
}

private func canAppendLetter(_ name: String, letter: Character) -> Bool {
  return name[name.count - 3] != name[name.count - 2] || name[name.count - 2] != name[name.count - 1] || name[name.count - 1] != letter
}

extension String {
  subscript(offset: Int) -> Character {
    self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)]
  }
}
```

Notes: I chose Swift because I'm a mobile developer with an interest in sci-fi, not a computer scientist or mathematician :)

Another Note: did I put this in the right StackXXX network? Happy to move it if not!

Comment: I think it fits this stack exchange as its not only code \ question about code, and asks something more general than this. Welcome! In my opinion, and its only my opinion, even though the book was written in 1953, its still a fictional book, and probably they didn't really calculate how much time was required with the machines they had in the day, and might have just guessed an arbitrary number that seemed big enough (and not too big as well). Once again, this was only my opinion.

Comment: I reckon your program must be quite slow, as generating 9 billion  permutations of length 9 should probably take a matter of minutes rather than hours. This is based on the rule of thumb sometimes used in competitive programming that you can do about 10^8 "simple" operations per second. (I didn't read your code)

Comment: I tried it out and get a program going through all the possibilities in less than two minutes on a machine which is not very fast (I didn't time it exactly). Although I count 10577400912 strings rather than 9 billion, so I might have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Tassle, you didn't make a mistake. The number of such strings is [like you reported](https://pastebin.com/1tCBrpxF).